# Images from remote source not displaying in iOS release version of React Native app

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm coming up against some issues with the release version of my React Native application in iOS. In the simulator, images from remote sources are displaying perfectly fine. However, when I build the app and release it for testing (using testflight to test), the images do not display and the location where the image should be is just empty.

I came across some issues on Github which were similar but they more relevant when images are not displaying in the simulator either. Link [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279) to see one such issue. I have added the fix for this to my application to see if it would work but it didn't.

I am using react-native v0.63.2 and xCode v12.4.

Any help will be much appreciated.